# Comunicação com a API do Google Calendar usando REST

Tags: java, json, api, google-calendar

Estou a usar `Scribe` para fazer autenticação com a `API` do `Google Calendar`.
A autenticação com o Google é feita com sucesso retornando o `accessToken` sem problemas.
Quando tento adicionar um `CalendarList`, através do seguinte código:

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList");
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        message.put("id", "Teste 1");
        request.addPayload(message.toJSONString());
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
```

O Google retorna o seguinte erro `this api does not support parsing form-encoded input`

Como é que devo construir o request em JSON para que tenha resposta por parte da Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void createNewCalendarList(OAuthService service){
        Token newAccessToken = new Token( API_USER_TOKEN, API_USER_SECRET);
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars");
        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json ; charset=UTF-8");
        payload.put("summary", "Meeto");
        request.addPayload(payload.toJSONString());
        service.signRequest(newAccessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
        System.out.println("Reposta dos tipos da google: " + response.getBody());
    }
```

Tive que adicionar um Content-type, e um payload com todos os argumentos necessários. Usei como base exemplos do seguinte link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert